# How to update just the time in a DateTime using XAML and C#

Tags: c#, xaml, datetime, windows-phone-8.1, timepicker

I am writing my first Windows Phone 8.1 app using c# and XAML, and I am trying to update just the time part of a datetime object that is bound to a timepicker control. At the moment changing the time sets the date as the current date.

Comment: Save the original datetime, and after user chose the time, create a new instance using the original date and the new time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to keep your date and set the time to : 23h 59m 59sec

```
yourDateTime = yourDateTime.Date + new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59); // where arguments are (hours, min, sec)
```